# Error "Module not found" while create-react-app and npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to run create-react-app and after entering npm start I am getting this error

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\project#1\client\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10' in 'C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\project#1\client\my-app'
ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\project#1\client\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10' in 'C:\Users\sande\OneDrive\Desktop\project#1\client\my-app'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Comment: Don't know if it comes from here, but you can try to remove the `#` from your folder `project#1`

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem while reading the directory because there is a # character in your file path. Do not use # and similar signs in your directory path. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I change my path and remove all `#` form it.

It should be like this `#React/myProject/project#1` => `React/myProject/project1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, it resolved the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).